# How do I select a group of child elements from a parent element of a particular class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

If I have a table as in this example:

```
<table class="detailView">
   <tr>
      <td>Value1</td>
      <td>value2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How do I style the `<tr>` and `<td>` elements **only if the table is of** `class="detailView"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a CSS class selector:

```
table.detailView tr {
    // your CSS properties
}

table.detailView td {
    // your CSS properties
}
```

If your table does not have the `detailView` class no style will be applied.